# align two Bootstrap 4 Navbars

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am facing the problem with the alignment of two navbars stacked on each other following is my code.i want to align upper navbar with lower navbar. I am adding oiginal image and my code result.I have tried in many ways like nesting both navbar in one but the alignment have little problem. Is there any problem with buttons or something else.Please help [image: Original Image]
[image: What my code is displaying]

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="F:/Theme Development/New folder/facebook.png" style="margin-right:2rem;vertical-align:text-top;height:55px;" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="F:/Theme Development/New folder/instagram.png" style="margin-right:2rem;vertical-align:text-top;height:55px;" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="F:/Theme Development/New folder/linkdin.png" style="margin-right:2rem;vertical-align:text-top;height:55px;" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="F:/Theme Development/New folder/twitter.png" style="margin-right:2rem;vertical-align:text-top;height:55px;" />
                    </a>
                </li>


                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #685dadfa;border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:30px;font-family: inherit"
                        href="#">
                        <img src="F:/Theme Development/New folder/lock1.png" style="vertical-align:sub" /> REGISTER</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:1rem;background-color: #179c95;border:0px;border-radius:0px;font-size:30px;font-family: inherit"
                        href="#">
                        <img src="F:/Theme Development/New folder/sign_in.png" style="vertical-align:sub;" /> LOG IN</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" style="background-color:white">

        <a class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1" style="font-family:Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif" href="#">Website Logo</a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Post a Job</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Post Resume</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!--/div-->
    </nav>
```

Comment: i am using bootstrap from cdn

Comment: its not working see login button right border and "contact us" button border login button border is little outside...and that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is padding around the `<a>` elements, the green part in the screenshot below:

[image]

If you want the right side of "Contact Us" and the "Log in" button to line up, add `padding-right: 0;` to the `<a>` for "Contact Us"

```
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" style="padding-right:0;">Contact Us</a>
            </li>
```

[image]

Comment: @AsadMarwat yes, I recommend learning about writing css outside of your html tags. See https://w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp to see the different ways of adding css, and https://w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp for some css syntax